# how to get the color code of pixel in windows 8 store app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, pixel, color-codes

I am using one image and i want to get the color code of the image on tap.
so for that I get the position of the tapping area successfully in the form of x and y coordinates.

```
Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(image1);
int x = Convert.ToInt32(clickPoint.X);
int y = Convert.ToInt32(clickPoint.Y);
```

But I am not able to get the pixel color code i have tried like below code :

```
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(x, y);
writeableBmp.GetBitmapContext();
Windows.UI.Color color = writeableBmp.GetPixel(120,120);
```

I am always getting color code of white({#00000000})

Comment: You should provide more code. From the looks of it you create new writable bitmap and immediately query a pixel. Since writable bitmap was not initialized you get back default transparent (not white) color.

Comment: @Denis i am not getting how to give the source of image to writable bitmap

Comment: @Denis Not able to initialize source to the WriteableBitmap,  WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromResource(App.imageName); Worked for windows phone 7, but it is not working gor windows phone 8, please help.